# Convert SQL Group to equivalent in Linq for Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I use EF 4 and c#, MS SQL 2008.

I have a T-SQL:

```
select COUNT(*)
from CmsContents
where IsPublished = 1 and isDeleted = 0
GROUP BY Day(Date)
```

I need convert it to EF, but I'm not able to get it.

Here what I'm using:

```
            var contentsByMonth = context.CmsContents
                .Where(c => c.IsPublished == true & c.IsDeleted == false)
                .GroupBy(c => c.Date.Month).ToList().Count();
```

Could you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var contentsByMonth = context.CmsContents
                .Where(c => c.IsPublished == true & c.IsDeleted == false)
                .GroupBy(c => c.Date.Day)
                .Select(g => new {Day = g.Key, Counts = g.Count()})
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I always forget about Date.Day notsupported

Comment: like .GroupBy(c => c.Date.Month).Select(g=>new { g.Count(), c.Date}).ToList(); but does not work.. any idea???

Comment: I tested this after I answered with EF, SQL 2008, but c.Date.Day it doesn't work, so you might use c=>SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd",c.Date) and reference System.Data.Objects.SqlClient. See more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(VS.100).aspx

Comment: So you need to use g.Key, it is the value on you're grouping, which is an integer. You can't access c.Date anymore here, only the "group" objects

Comment: ok i tried your code but it saying G does not exist in the context? are you sure you code is fine?

Comment: it is fine now, I really appreciate your help on this. Thanks